# Duplicate 'Worksheet A' when creating new row in a 'Worksheet B'

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

'Worksheet B' is a sales tracker, it contains typically sales tracking info.

Assume that in 'column A' of 'Worksheet B' a new entry is added under 'Client Name' = "John Smith"

Upon data entry in column A, I want an action where 'Worksheet A' is duplicated

I'm trying to keep it basic here so that maybe I can get some help with the framework of the script and do the rest myself.

Comment: You can use the macro recorder to get your project started.

Comment: Is this VBA? Is this for Google Apps Script? Please double check your question as the tags are very misleading, they are two very different languages.

Comment: Seems tags got updated already, thank you stats exchange!

Comment: do you mean that you want to duplicate new entry from worksheet B to worksheet A ?

Comment: or you want to make a new worksheet (worksheet A duplicate) for new entry?

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("ID_or_URL_of_your_worksheet_here", "sheet_name_here!A1")
```

Comment: Re-wrote my question to make it a bit clearer, unfortunately importrange wont cut it

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output?